# Как парсить json если в нем есть значения с кавычкой?

Tags: python

Пробую таким способом:

```py
data = response.json()
for item in data['result']['list']:
    print(item['Id'])
```

После первого найденного значения, второй перестает перебирать и показывает ошибку

> KeyError: 'Id'

структура json такая:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "Info": {
      "Msg": {
        "is": 0
      }
    },
    "total": 2,
    "list": [
      {
        "Id": 111,   
        "name": "111111",
        "host": {
          "is": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": 222,
        "name": "222"222",
        "host": {
          "is": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print (*item['Id'])
KeyError: 'Id'
```

Из-за того что в ключе значения `name` есть ковычка, я не могу получить вывод без ошибки

Comment: из-за того, что там есть к**а**вычка это невалидный джейсон. Если кавычку убрать, то ваш код работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик в том и проблема что такой json мне нужно парсить в котором есть ковычка внутри ковычек.

Comment: Покажите, что **на самом деле** печатает `print(data)`, там не может быть такой структуры в `data`. А уже от этого можно будет дальше плясать.

Comment: В валидном JSON кавычка в строковом значении должна экранироваться при помощи `'\'`: `"name": ""name": "222\"222""`

Comment: @Nowhere Man Я допустил ошибку в примере  из за невнимательности ...  попробую выявить причину из за чего не могу парсить все значения.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас в каких-то записях списка просто нет ключа `"Id"` и нужно это проверять прежде, чем брать значение по этому ключу.

Comment: @Эникейщик ошибка в вопросе противоречит теме вопроса. Дело не в кавычке внутри json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не валидный `json` в вопросе. При приведении данной структуры к словарю вы бы получили ошибку:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter....
```

Но у вас этого нет. Ошибка говорит о другом.

Чтобы убрать исключение при обращении к несуществующему ключу, используйте метод `get`

```py
data = response.json()
for item in data['result']['list']:
    print(item.get("Id"))
```

Этот же метод можете использовать для условий, например

```py
for item in data['result']['list']:
    if item.get("Id"):
         print(item.get("Id"))
```

То есть при вызове метода если ключ не найден, то просто вернется `None` и данная ветка условия не сработает. В этом случае будьте осторожны, поскольку значение под этим ключом тоже может быть `None`. В таком случае ветка тоже не сработает

Comment: У меня все заработало с вашим способом! Спасибо.

Comment: @bauna28 на здоровье )

Comment: можете подсказать как убрать из вывода все значения None?

Comment: @bauna28 не просто так я добавил в ответ раздел для условия. Если вы примените это условие, то вы не будете получать `None` в выводе

Comment: Если вас не затруднит покажите пример как это сделать?

Comment: @bauna28 смотрите в ответе, второй блок кода

Comment: благодарю за помощь 

Comment: @bauna28 на здоровье. С вас плюс один)